# IBM z/OS TSO ISPF Editor Cancel command - how to add "Are You Sure?" query dialog

Tags: mainframe, ispf

Using the ISPF Editor on z/OS (MVS) it happened several times to me that I entered then "can" (cancel) line command when I actually meant "reset". This cancelled my edit session so I lost my changes.

I would like to add a small dialog window asking the safety question "Are you Sure?" to the built-in can(cel) command.

How can that be achieved?

As far as i know, can/cancel will not search sysexec or the like, so I wouldn't know how to bind / override the cancel command with my own rexx exec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an Edit session, use the EDSET line command, scroll down and select the  `_ Confirm Cancel/Move/Replace` option.

Answer (score 2):

There’s a `CONFIRM` parameter that you have to set up for the ISPF editor:

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.1.0?topic=services-edit-edit-data-set

It will ask you to confirm with some of the problematic commands.

Comment: Thank you, you got me on the right track:

EDSET has a CONFIRM option.

Comment: Oh, yes! I didn’t remember about the panel to set it up. There are things that you look at every few years…

Answer (score 0):

If the Action Bar has not been disabled you can also use the Edit Settings pull down choice.  It runs EDSET.